# arch linux recognizes the partitions and hard disks wrongly

Tags: linux, arch-linux, udev, block-device

My arch Linux system does not recognize neither the partition nor the hard disk in which it is installed. it is installed on `/dev/sdb1` but it recognizes that as `/dev/sdc1` and the initialization goes wrong. It doesn't matter which grub is used: either arch's or other distro's that is installed in another partition. When I try to initialize arch there comes `/dev/sdc1` instead of `/dev/sdb1`. that started after I installed the fourth hd (/dev/sdd). but only with arch. I Have other distros in other partitions and there is no problem at all to initialize them. I have removed `/dev/sdd` for a test and solved the problem, but I need the fourth hd installed.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Use [peristent block device naming](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Persistent_block_device_naming)...

Answer (score 3):

Unless you can't (or don't want to) use [persistent device naming](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Persistent_block_device_naming) (mentioned by @jasonwryan in his comment), you can:

- try swapping the installed drives until you achieve the desired outcome. This however, will be tedious and error prone, plus it is likely to break the other installed OSes.
- tell your bootloader to pass `root=/dev/sdc1` to the kernel when booting Arch. That will make sure that the kernel will mount the right file system when mounting `/`. You may need to change this when adding/removing/moving HDDs.